# ruby devise encrypted password decrypt in django

Tags: django, ruby, bcrypt

First my database was connected to ruby.Ruby devise uses Bcrypt password by default to hash passwords.

I am building same app in django but also want that old users can login using django app that is only possible if django can decrypt ruby hashed password stored in mysql database.

By default django password hashing looks something like this:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$180000$cZxgIsN0sthv$XnAOHJiWIX1E1/p4livZCcmf6DmmKi2FZPrKbDZIpfM=
```

When i changed default password haser in django to Bycrypt algorithm passwords are stored something like this:

```
bcrypt_sha256$$2b$12$MUA0prRIYOnu63HAFP9tP.RsNVyO.ApAv.zTJX5GOBb2eBQ.8hz.W
```

IN database ruby passwords are stored something like this:

```
$2a$12$tBfIVsgQvDSM8WOu9SDpGupSaFbHXJbAT8lOtkvYCMO5NrOVjy9Y2
```

Inorder to decrypt ruby written passwords i tried adding "bcrypt_sha256$" and "bcrypt$" before ruby passwords to make it django bcrypt format but it does not work.